# Multiple custom post types using the same taxonomy = URL frustrations

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I have two custom post types:

- Events
- Businesses

I have a new taxonomy that both these CTP's share:

- Locations

If I go to "domain.com/events/"  I see an archive of all the events, and if I go to "domain.com/businesses/" I see an archive of all the businesses. So far, so good.

If I go to "domain.com/locations/" I see an archive of all the events AND businesses, which is Ok.

However, how do I view the event locations only? "domain.com/locations/events" or "domain.com/events/locations" doesn't work.

Do I have to change the rewrite settings for either the locations taxonomy or the CPT? It seems I'm stuck!

Comment: Permalinks are current set to just /%postname%/ by the way.

Comment: _"If I go to 'domain.com/locations/' I see an archive of all the events AND businesses, which is Ok."_ Have you added a custom rewrite rule for that? Normally WP with this url look for a page with the slug 'locations'. Maybe do you intend 'domain.com/locations/a-location'?

Comment: No, haven't added anything custom. The taxonomy has been defined for BOTH the post types though, so wouldn't this be normal function?

Comment: @Buckers @g-m it is a normal function I think, it would happen if when generating the rewrite rules for the taxonomy if the `walk_dirs` parameter was true. The rule would return posts with any location term assigned.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to add some new rewrite rules, thankfully WordPress makes it fairly straightforward using a few function calls.

```
// use the init action to modify rewrite rules
add_action( 'init', function() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    // add rewrite tag for the post type
    // - %posttype% is a new tag that will be replaced with the regex in the actual query
    // - the regex will extract the post_type name from the URL and use it in the query
    add_rewrite_tag( '%posttype%', '([^/]+)', 'post_type=' );

    // create the new permastruct by combining the post type & taxonomy permastructs
    // - custom taxonomies and post types are added to the extra_permastructs array in WP_Rewrite
    // - change 'category' to desired taxonomy
    // - output will be '%posttype%/category/%category%'
    $types_and_cats_permastruct = '%posttype%' . $wp_rewrite->get_extra_permastruct( 'category' );

    // add the permastruct for post type & taxonomy
    add_permastruct( 'post_type_and_category', $types_and_cats_permastruct, array(
        'with_front' => true,           //  - with_front (bool) - Should the structure be prepended with WP_Rewrite::$front? Default is true.
        'ep_mask' => EP_ALL_ARCHIVES,   //  - ep_mask (int) - Endpoint mask defining what endpoints are added to the structure. Default is EP_NONE.
        'paged' => true,                //  - paged (bool) - Should archive pagination rules be added for the structure? Default is true.
        'feed' => true,                 //  - feed (bool) - Should feed rewrite rules be added for the structure? Default is true.
        'forcomments' => false,         //  - forcomments (bool) - Should the feed rules be a query for a comments feed? Default is false.
        'walk_dirs' => false,           //  - walk_dirs (bool) - Should the 'directories' making up the structure be walked over and rewrite
                                        //    rules built for each in turn? Default is true.
        'endpoints' => true             //  - endpoints (bool) - Should endpoints be applied to the generated rewrite rules? Default is true.
    ) );

} );
```

So to explain what I'm doing above:

1. Adding a rewrite tag with [`add_rewrite_tag()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag) so that when you put the custom post type name into the URL (eg. /events/location/uk/) it will be recognised by the regular expression and the resulting query WP runs would contain `post_type=events`
2. Making a new permastruct to generate rules for using the tag we just added and the existing taxonomy permastruct, in your case this would be location so `/event/location/uk` will show uk events and `/business/location/uk` will show uk businesses
3. Adding the new permastruct with [`add_permastruct()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_permastruct) so that WP generates the new rewrite rules whenever permalinks are refreshed. In the 3rd parameter it's very important to have `walk_dirs` set to false as you'll get some undesirable aggressive rewrite rules with archives for `/%posttype%/category/` and `/%posttype%/`

### Gotchas

- Generating links - if you want to use `the_terms()` to output location links for a business or event that only shows the originating post type you'll have to filter the URLs or write a custom function to output URLs to match your permastruct
- If you never want an archive listing both events and businesses then 2 separate taxonomies is a better idea as you'll more easily be able to tell if a term has any posts in it eg. when generating links and deciding whether to output a link to an empty archive or not. In that case [@richard-howarth's answer is correct](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/113671/1733)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the slug to use in the args when calling the register_taxonomy function by using 'rewrite'.

So, you'd have something like the following:

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug'=>'events/locations' )
);
register_taxonomy( 'event_location_tax_name', 'event_location_cpt_name', $args );
```

And then replicate for Businesses :

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug'=>'businesses/locations' )
);
register_taxonomy( 'business_location_tax_name', 'business_location_cpt_name', $args );
```

Hope that helps?!

Thanks
Rik

Comment: Wouldn't that create two separate taxonomies though? I would like to share the same taxonomy, as all the terms would be the same.

Comment: Can you do something like 'rewrite'=>array('slug'=>'%post_type%/locations') and then pass the CPTs as an array into the register_taxonomy : array( 'event_location_cpt_name', 'business_location_cpt_name')? I haven't actually tried myself (so could be rubbish!), but it might depend on how WP handles %post_type%