# CPT posts listed by category with custom rewrite URL, please help!

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, wp-query, urls

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have 10 total dessert recipes (in shared dessert category) that are divided by 2 custom post types. I want to create 3 different views of these posts with the custom URL structure described below:

1. Recipes 1-3 (CPT "a") with URL: "home/%posttype%/%category%/"
2. Recipes 4-10 (CPT "b") with URL: "home/%posttype%/%category%/"
3. Recipes 1-10 (all CPTs) with URL: "home/%category%/"

I have searched far and wide for an answer that completes both the URL and content aspects of my goal, but everything I've tried only addresses one or the other.

For example: For the content, I've used `get_posts()` parameters to view specific category and post type, but since the template is assigned to a "page" the wordpress generated URL does not include the custom post type and the result is:

home/%pagename%/

For the URL, I've tried to use the init action to modify rewrite rules as suggested in this forum [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/135320/54882) and although this creates a URL structure exactly as I want it, the content output for the URL does not match what would be expected. The result is that all three URLs have all 10 recipes (essentially the general category archive page):

"home/%posttype%/%category%/" is the same as "home/%category%/" and I can't figure out why.

I've also added a filter to `pre_get_posts` to include my CPTs in the main query so that they show up at all. Not sure if there is a better way to do this in case it is interfering with the URL rewrite, although considering I took the code from the [WP codex here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) under "Custom Post Types in the Main Query" I think the problem/solution is somewhere I don't seem to be looking.

I can't imagine that what I want is supposed to be that complicated. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I did look at your code and saw you changed the original code.

To make it more clear what you can achieve with this snippet. You would end up with the following permalinks:

```
/recetas-argentinas/category/desserts
```

> Shows all post with the post_type recetas-argentinas and with the
>   category desserts.

```
/recetas-argentinas/my-single-recept-post
```

> Shows a single post of the post_type recetas-argentinas.

I did just use the code snippet from the [original link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/135320/54882) and it was working for me.

Here is a screenshot of the rewrite analyzer to show how it works. Basically you enter a URL in the input field on the top and the plugin will show you which rewrite-rules will be matched by this URL:

[image: Showing usage of Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer]

Also please be aware that the `Category base` in your permalink settings also has a influence to this. To have a permalink structure like above you would have to leave it empty.

Hope this is helping you to reach your target.

---

***Old answer***

Not sure I totally get your question, but from the following two sentences:

> I've managed to use WP_query to create a page template ***[...]***
>   However, I can't figure out the URL structures or slugs for this filtered category archive

A page template doesn't have a permalink-structure. It's nothing more then a template assigned to a single page - even if you use it to display a "archive like" list of posts.

Two other suggestions:

- For any rewrite problems (especially if it's about conflicting rewrite structs) it's a good idea to debug your permalinks with the [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/).
- [register_post_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) has extensive support for creating custom permalink options which can help you avoid permalink conflicts.

Even if this is no direct answer to your question, I hope this is helping you somewhat further.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I know my question is confusing, probably because I am confused myself.

Comment: Oops...hit the return button too quick! At the moment, don't have any conflicting slugs because I have just been testing things. I am also aware of the need to flush permalinks if I make any rewrite changes. However, let me try and clarify my question...

Essentially, I want 3 views of the same content. I have been able to achieve this using wp_query in a custom page template. But I haven't been able to get the URL structure I desire for these 3 views.

Comment: If I have 10 dessert recipes, I want to be able to view them the final ways:

1-3 on one view
4-10 on another
1-10 on a third //this one being the standard category archive

My approach for the content is to use 3 different templates, but this may not work with the desired URL structure I mentioned in the question post.

Comment: One more thing! I also found this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/135320/54882

which appears to be an even better approach than my wp_query option because the way I interpret it is that it takes care of both the URL structure and the desired content at the same time. However, I could not get it to work. Maybe I am missing something simple, but I copied the code into my functions.php file, flushed the permalinks, and tried to visit mysite.com/argentine_recipes/category/desserts or mysite.com/argentine_recipes/desserts and it didn't work. Got redirected to a single post and then got a 404

Comment: That question really seems to be what you are searching for. Hard to tell why it's not working for you. Did you try the debug plugin mentioned above? Is the permastruct added to your global `$wp_rewrite`s?

Comment: I did try plugin, but I don't really understand what I'm looking at. Anything with regex syntax is worse than greek to me. The only red line error I see is `.*wp-register.php$  register: true` with the "register: true" crossed out in red. It doesn't seem like the URL rewrite structure is even referenced in the rewrite analyzer because I think most of what I see is generated by WP.

I pasted the analyzer results and my functions.php code on pastebin if you wouldn't mind taking a look. http://pastebin.com/AGLYkCRc I'm not sure how to check if the permastruct is added to global `wp_rewrite` Thx

Comment: @user3784685 I edited my answer. Please be aware that you need to flush your permalinks everytime you change something!

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Sorry I forgot that I did change the `with_front` to `false` when I was trying things, but in its original form it did not work for me either. I think your note about the `Category base` was my issue at first. Once I changed my settings there I was able to access the URL (with /category/) without an error message. But, the content still isn't correct. It is showing regular posts along with my custom argentine post type, so essentially the page is identical to the default category archive. Could it have to do with the `// Show custom post types` code?

Comment: Tried removing 'post' from `$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'receta_argentina', 'receta_internacional' ) )` and that got rid of the regular post on /recetas-argentinas/category/desserts. Same thing for a second CPT (internacional), but it's not a solution because the omission is site wide. Any ideas?

Comment: You would need to edit the if-statement so it doesn't add 'posts' to the post_types if the post_type already is `receta_argentina` could look like this: `if ((is_home() xor is_tag() xor is_category()) && $query->is_main_query() && !in_array($query->query_vars['post_type'], array('receta_argentina', 'receta_internacional') ) )`.

Comment: Also I just realized, that the solution from the other post will only work if the CPT slug is the same as the CPT name. So you would need to use `receta_argentina` instead of `recetas-argentinas` as your rewrite slug when registering the post_type :|

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change the output at all. First I added the suggested code to if-statement. Then changed the CPT slugs to match CPT name. All three post types continue to show (I did flush permalink settings every time). I even tried removing the `xor is_category` to see if maybe the snippet from the original link would work on its own to no avail. I'm thinking that maybe I still need to use a template to filter out the other post types, however, I don't know how I would name it or connect it to the rewrite. It appears the category.php template is being called.

Comment: That's correct it's `category.php` or `archive.php` (http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png). But you should not need to use a template for that. Maybe you should have a look, if the permastruct is setting the post-type correctly. It's supposed to look like in the screenshot in my answer with `post_type = receta_argentina`.

Comment: Yes [my rewrite rule screen](http://puntanativa.com/dir/wp-content/uploads/rwrules.png) looks just like the screenshot you provided:  (I can't upload an img to this comment, so I provided a link--also keep in mind I changed the slug to match CPT name exactly). So the URL part of it would indicate that I'm only supposed to see the posts in both CPT and category, however on [the front end](http://puntanativa.com/dir/receta_argentina/category/empanadas/) I am still seeing all three post types.

Comment: (Be warned the site is a mess! I am focused on getting this functionality working. But you can see posts in each CPT, specified in post title, and posts with no "CPT" in title). In your test site, have you tested with actual content and the content is outputting as desired, or are you just going off what "should" happen based on rewrite analyzer and reading the code? I am totally stumped.